# SQL Audit options for update commands where an existing column does not change

Tags: sql, sql-server, audit-logging

I have a need to audit changes where triggers are not performing well enough to use. In the audit I need to know exactly who made the change based on a column named LastModifiedBy (gathered at login and used in inserts and updates). We use a single SQL account to access the database so I cant use that to tie it to a user.

Scenario: Now we are researching the SQL transaction Log to determine what has changed. Table has a LastUpdatedBy column we used with trigger solution.  With previous solution I had before and after transaction data so I could tell if the user making the change was the same user or a new user.

Problem: While looking at tools like DBForge Transaction Log and ApexSQL Audit I cant seem to find a solution that works.  I can see the Update command but I can't tell if all the fields actually changed (Just because SQL says to update a field does not mean it actually changed value).  ApexSQL Audit does have a before and after capability but if the LastUpdatedBy field does not change then I don't know what the original value is.

Trigger problem: Large data updates and inserts are crushing performance because of the triggers.  I am gathering before and after data in the triggers so I can tell exactly what changed.  But this volume of data is taking a 2 second update of 1000 rows and making it last longer than 3 minutes.

Comment: Sounds like you have loops in your triggers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.